# Sharing location (map) with WhatsApp?

Tags: objective-c, whatsapp

I've noticed WhatsApp has recently(?) enabled sharing location service and since we can open WhatsApp to send pictures/videos I thought maybe now there's a way to also send location?

I haven't really found anything on that matter yet but maybe someone can tell me if it's available now!

Answer (score 3):

You can share a location with WhatsApp through the custom URL scheme. Take a look at the following example.

```
NSString *geoMessage = @"geo:23.1097,-82.4094";
NSString *whatsappURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@", geoMessage];
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:whatsappURLString];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:whatsappURL];
} else {
    // WhatsApp not installed
}
```

For more info, see WhatsApp's FAQ page about the custom URL scheme:
http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

**Update:**

I think from newer version of WhatsApp it is not possible.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a place where this is documented ?

Comment: @SamhanSalahuddin This is documented on the website of WhatsApp. See: http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: This is NOT sharing location. This is just sending a literal coordinates in string.. Why would you even suggest this

Comment: @Hitesh have you tried .. Beacause i can't find it in documentation ...Please check it ...